# Keyboard shortcut to switch focus between multiple displays on OS X 10.9+

Tags: keyboard, display, macos

The fact that each monitor acts on its own in OS X Mavericks is pretty cool. However, I find that I have to use my mouse and click on the unfocused monitor before I can actually slide back and forth its screens (or spaces).

What's the keyboard shortcut to switch focus to another monitor?

**update:** follow up [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116557/how-to-make-each-display-a-separate-space-yet-have-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move)

Comment: doesn't really solve the problem because you have to move you hand to your mouse to move the pointer into the other screen to then put you hand back on the keyboard for the Control + Arrow the only people that might profit are Lefties who use the mouse left-handed.
best would be a Shift + Control + Arrow to switch between screens. Now to figure a way to get that Macro to work.

Comment: @Stephan that's exactly what i'm asking about

Comment: cmd + tab usually works for me when trying to switch from my laptop to my external monitor.

Comment: It's sad that none of the suggested solutions work for Mac OS Sierra... I think this feature should be built-in the OS.

Comment: i updated my [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116889/43968) below.. hopefully it better addresses the problem

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer this question, but as of 2022 you can accomplish this rather easily with BetterTouchTool: Create one keyboard shortcut with three assigned actions (Save Current Mouse Position, Move Mouse to Position, and Left Click) and one keyboard shortcut with two assigned actions (Restore Saved Mouse Position and Left Click).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<s>I just found an open source window manager called [slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate).. From my point of view it's better than **divvy** and better than **sizeup**.. and it has a key binding for switching focus between screens. Its default key bindings are shown [here](https://github.com/jigish/slate/blob/master/Slate/default.slate) (very customizable).. it defaults to~  <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd></s>

**bonus:** here is my slate [config file](https://github.com/abbood/slateConfig).. it can give you some ideas to get you started

## update

From the comments I realized that my above answer isn't about switching focus, rather it's about throwing windows around from one monitor to another. That's not what the question was about.

This solution works assuming that you already have application windows already open in all your monitors..

Take a look at this screenshot to understand my solution (click on it to zoom):

[image]

**scenario 1**
i simply click on <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between the applications (ie i switch from chrome which is on the already focused monitor to terminal which is on the monitor i want to focus on

**scenario 2**
I do the same simply by clicking on <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>, this makes me switch between windows of the *same* application.. in the example below i got chrome windows in all three monitors, so I simply go through them until I reach the window I want to switch focus to..

### update 2: works using skhd + yabai

This solution requires that you install both [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai) and [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd).

in your skhd config file put something like this (you can adjust the keybindings and focus numbers to your liking):

```
ctrl + alt - right : yabai -m display --focus 1
ctrl + alt - left : yabai -m display --focus 2
```

Comment: How did you get this to work? I've been playing with Slate, but it seems like those commands just give focus to the  next window to the right or left of the current one. Are you able to get it to solve the problem from your original question?

Comment: yeah it did @shanebonham.. you just have to go through the config file and make sure you're doing the right command

Comment: I don't think this exists with slate currently - https://github.com/jigish/slate/issues/458 I would really like to see this as well.

Comment: @abbood This absolutely doesn't work, it's can change focus between apps but not between monitors, i've tries everything, and i've read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked out of the box without having to touch the config file or create one. CMD + right arrow/left arrow switches focus between monitors. (NOTE - I'm using two external monitors with the actual laptop closed, in clamshell). None of the above solutions worked for me on OSX El Capitan.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Not sure about the "working out of the box" experience. I am on Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: the guys complaining are right.. i updated the answer

Comment: Both options (scenarios) don't solve the problem. Indeed, they move focus to the other app / window, but they *don't* move focus to the other screen in a _stronger_ sense: when you do Ctrl+Arrow to side windows (spaces) you are still stuck at the original screen.

Answer (score 55):

Here's a way that works from the keyboard:

1. Open `System Preferences -> Keyboard` and click the `Shortcuts` tab.
2. Choose `Mission Control` from the sidebar.
3. Scroll down until you see Mission Control listed in the main panel; check its box if not checked, and click the disclosure triangle.
4. You should see `Move left a space`, `Move right a space`, and then a series of `Switch to Desktop 1`, `Switch to Desktop 2`, etc. for as many desktop spaces as you have going at the moment.
5. Check all of the boxes of the `Switch to Desktop N` type.
6. In my prefs, each of those Switch-tos has a shortcut already there - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, ... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-N, where N is the Desktop number (Control key is shown as a carat ('^'). You can assign whatever you want to these, but keeping them in a sequential scheme helps, so I suggest leaving them as is.
7. Now, you can switch among your functioning desktops (aka Spaces), and if one you choose is on the other display, focus will shift to that display.
8. If you don't remember which number a Desktop is, you could first use your shortcut for Mission Control itself (mine is <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>-<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>, which I think was the default, but again you can set that for whatever you want). You'll see your current numbered Desktops, and can then use the appropriate shortcut. Press <kbd>⎋ Esc</kbd> to get out of Mission Control.
9. I see that if I have all of the Switch-tos checked, then if I had another Desktop and check keyboard shortcuts again, the new Desktop is added to the Switch-to list and its shortcut is checked as well. So no need to go back to Prefs after the above steps.

Thanks for stimulating me to poke into this. I was having the same frustration as you and others!

ADDED for El Capitan: In my October 31 2016 note I describe my latest finding for switching to a space in the external display. It seems you need at least two spaces defined on your external display, and then you need to hit Control-N, Control-M, and you will be live in space M, where N & M are space numbers of spaces on the external display.

Comment: i see the value in what you're saying.. although i still wouldn't consider it ideal. b/c you are using dekstop numbers.. and to go back and forth to a specifically numbered desktop forces you to remember it (having to go through mission control to see the number of a desktop defeats the whole point of a 'shortcut').. the number one rule in human/computer interaction is "don't make me think".. i was hoping for something that's more intiuitive.. like <+[ctr] or smtn.. that requires 0 brain memory/processing on the user's part.. but i still gave you a +1 :)

Comment: after testing with your solution.. it definitely saves time.. but it doesn't address the main problem: **shifting focus**.. b/c even if it shows a screen i'm interested in.. that screen is still not in focus.. and so i still gotta take my hands of the keyboard and put my mouse on that screen.. then move my hands back to my keyboard.. :(

Comment: Hmmm. If I use the Control-N shortcut described above (where N is the Desktop number), the display I just switched to gets focus if it wasn't the desktop in view on that display. If I press Control N+1, then Control-N, then Desktop N comes into focus. So I DO get to my chosen Desktop & display without leaving keyboard, but it takes an extra keyboard step, and seems to require having that N+1 Desktop available to switch to. Obviously sub-optimal, but it does avoid using the mouse.

Comment: The reason I picked [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107283/43968) answer is b/c it involved the act of switching between screens (ie ctrl + > or ctrl + <) and that in itself guarantees that the screen being switched to gets highlighted.. and it's very intuitive too (ie no numbers involved or intermediate steps)

Comment: +1 except for #9. Stays unchecked, so I have to go in the prefs and check it manually for each new desktop added.

Comment: @BruceVanAllen  I have 4 desktops/spaces going but my System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control only shows 'Switch to Desktop 1.'  There aren't any options to switch to Desktop N. Any thoughts?  I'm using Mavericks.

Comment: Sorry but I just tried it in El Capitan and it is not working :/ I can not change focus to my external display :/

Comment: I can't change focus to my external display too. :( (El Capitan)

Comment: OK, here's what I've found in El Capitan. (Assumes Sys Prefs:Mission Control: Displays Have Separate Spaces is checked.) 1. In Keyboard: Shortcuts: Mission Control the number of commands for "Switch to Desktop N" seems to be set by how many Desktop Spaces you ALREADY have defined. 2.If you have at least two spaces created on your external display

Comment: [Previous comment saved too soon.] 1. In Keyboard: Shortcuts: Mission Control the number of commands for "Switch to Desktop N" seems to be set by how many Desktop Spaces you ALREADY have defined. 2.You can see which number a space is by using your Mission Control Hot Corner (set if needed). 3. With at least two spaces created on my external display, say spaces number 3 & 4, this works: I am in the main display, space #1; if I hit Control 3, then Control 4, I am in the external monitor, space 4. Then Control-N to switch among spaces on that display. See if this works for you.

Comment: Doesn't really switch between displays in Mac OS Sierra...

Comment: If only this switched focus for desktops that are already visible, this would be a pretty decent work around for the embarrassingly non-customizable displays that OS X provides.

Say I have Desktops 1 and 2 on my left monitor, with 2 currently visible. I cannot switch to Desktop 2, **and give it focus** without swapping to 1 and back to 2 first... Such a pity

Answer (score 24):

Best solution I've found thus far is to install the free [CatchMouse](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yc2l53prov9ts4/CatchMouse.zip?dl=0) utility off the app store.  It allows you to assign different keyboard shortcuts to "warp" the mouse pointer to the center of each monitor.  In my case I've mapped my left hand monitor to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, and the right one to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

**Note: The link to CatchMouse has been updated to an unknown and untrusted source. Download and use at your own risk!**

Comment: nice works well!

Comment: Lazy people can click here, all others need not apply: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/catchmouse/id439700005?mt=12

Comment: I gotta add that the suggestion above doesn't do the highlighting in itself.. so what I do is that once the mouse cursor is on the right screen.. i switch between screens using ctr+left or ctrl+right

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to be available in the US store currently.

Comment: CatchMouse is still available from the developer as of 2014-12: http://ftnew.com/catchmouse.html

Comment: Does anyone know where CatchMouse ended up or if there is an alternative? The link on the Mac App Store and the link to the developer in the comments here are all broken.

Comment: I was looking something like this long ago! ..thanks!

Comment: Not available on our region? Why? :(

Comment: [This github repo](https://github.com/ROUND/CatchMouse) seems to host it. This is the best solution as of now, in my opinion. July, 2017

Comment: I was unable to get CatchMouse working on Catalina, Feb 2020 :(

Comment: Echoing @DannyHarding: CatchMouse displays an enlarged cursor on the appropriate screen when the trigger is typed, but that's pretty much all it does. It does not give focus to the indicated screen.

Comment: I've confirmed Catchmouse works on big sur.

Answer (score 6):

(This should be a comment but I don't have the reputation to post one.)

I have the same issue. I work almost exclusively in full-screen apps and switch between them with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>◀︎</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>▶︎</kbd>. I like to work on my primary monitor and use the secondary for Messages. But I don't want to leave Messages visible when I'm not using it; I would rather switch back to the Desktop on the secondary monitor. But to put focus on the secondary monitor, I have to move the mouse pointer, totally defeating the time and effort savings of using the keyboard shortcut for app switching.

For what it's worth, you don't have to click on anything to change focus to a different monitor. You only need to move your mouse pointer where you want focus.

Comment: yeah the point is to avoid using the mouse all together for such a common and basic operation

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @Flavin Not only that your comment deserves to be a full-blown answer – it is the best answer. Embarrassingly, it is the best answer almost 9 years after!! I am stuck with the exact same problem, and i see no solution other than installing a piece of software from the wild web, which is a no go for me. However, your last comment makes the whole business of moving the mouse 50% less painful! I'll have to settle for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I use Keyboard Maestro to do just this.
I mapped the <kbd>F16</kbd> thru <kbd>F19</kbd> keys in this order.

<kbd>F16</kbd> Left monitor move left

<kbd>F17</kbd> Left monitor move right

<kbd>F18</kbd> Right monitor move left

<kbd>F19</kbd> Right monitor move right

I created 4 Keyboard Maestro Actions for this, one for each monitor and one for each direction. Here is the basic shortcut which gets adjusted accordingly:

1. Move the mouse over to whichever monitor without clicking.
2. Keystroke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-[left arrow] or [right arrow], depending.

Actually I changed the Keyboard Shortcut in System Preferences under mission control from:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Arrow to move left/right a space to:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>left/right arrow</kbd> to free up the simpler control arrows for other activities. I also changed the Keyboard Maestro Macro to reflect the change.

While at it I also have the following mission control operations.

<kbd>F13</kbd> Show desktop

<kbd>F14</kbd> Show application windows

<kbd>F15</kbd> Mission Control

I have it set up for the mouse to stay on the changed monitor but it could easily be set to return to where it started from.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how to get Keyboard Maestro to move the mouse to my laptop monitor, so in case anyone else is having trouble too, I got it working like this:

`just move` at `SCREEN(Internal,MidX)`, `SCREEN(Internal,MidY)` relative to the `absolute position`

Comment: This is the best answer, Keyboard Maestro is well developed, is currently supported on Sierra, and has so many powerful options to control the mouse, this is awesome!

Answer (score 5):

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) can help you do that.

In my case, I use CTRL + 0,1,2 to refer screen 0, 1, 2. Below is how I configure that. Also, 0,1,2 on number pad is close to your arrow keys, then you can use CTRL + arrows to switch windows on selected display.

Notice, I use click because I want to move the focus to the window under cursor.

[image: mouse movement to select display]

Comment: I used this tip to make it work for me for dual monitors. Here is what I did to add shortcut for my non main monitor. It only gives the option relative to main screen window. So to make the mouse move to the left display, I set the relative mouse position to -500.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the MacOS window manager inspired by xmonad called [Amethyst](https://ianyh.com/amethyst/) which has some key-bindings (default) <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to cycle the mouse pointer between screens. There's more it can do of course.