# Keyboard shorcut to switch focus between displays on Mavericks

Tags: macos

I was wondering if there was a shortcut or solution to switch focus between different displays since I'm using a mac air with an external monitor. Often times I have to use the mouse just to focus on another application on a different display. Would really speed up the work flow if I can focus on apps in different displays.

Also I use full screen apps so I take advantage of desktop switching by hitting control + left or right thats why I need to be able to first focus on an app on either screen 1 or two then start switching apps or just use the app on that screen.

Comment: Identical to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106559/keyboard-shorcut-to-switch-focus-between-multiple-displays-on-os-x-mavericks?rq=1

Comment: I see that it kind of identical but I'm looking for a solution where I can focus on an app and not just simply put my mouse on a display. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have always used the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + TAB keyboard shortcut to switch focus between applications.  It should not matter if an application is on a different screen for this shortcut to work.

Comment: command + Tab is slow when you have lots of applications open and the app is near the end of the stacks. Plus I use full screen apps so I often just switch to the right screen then use control + left or right to get to the application but I just to use the mouse to move to the right screen first since control + direction only works for the screen the mouse is currently on.