# Is it possible to switch the desktops of multiple displays without moving the mouse? (Mavericks)

Tags: keyboard, macos, display, spaces

I have been loving Maverick's new "Displays have separate spaces" functionality; however, I have just one issue with it. I usually use a keyboard shortcut to change spaces (i.e.⌘ + → and ⌘ + ←), and this action changes the space of whichever display the mouse is on. When I am working, I dislike having to think about where the mouse is, so I was wondering if it is possible to have something like four keyboard shortcut: two for left/right on the internal display, and two for the left/right on the external display? Or if there was any other convenient solution to this little annoyance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) can do this using a macro such as the following:

[image: Test]

Answer (score 1):

After a little more research, I discovered [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107283/33265) by user60838, and I believe it solves my problem as well. Seeing as my question is not the same as the question asked in that thread, I am leaving my post up and not deleting it. If the mods deem it redundant please feel free to delete this.