# How do I switch monitor focus with the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, display, spaces

I have 2 monitors connected to my Mac. 
Each monitor has multiple spaces setup, for example - monitor 1 has Desktop 1, 2 & 3 and monitor 2 has Desktop 4 & 5.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> only move between spaces on the currently focused monitor.

However, I can't find how to switch monitor focus using the keyboard.

If focus is on monitor 1, I need to point and click my mouse on monitor 2 and only then can I switch spaces on monitor 2.

Even if I switch to an application open on monitor 2 using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, the monitor focus and space switching still occurs on monitor 1.

Using Yosemite.

Comment: When you say "Even if I switch to an application open on monitor 2 using ctrl+tab,"  do you mean cmd+tab ?

Comment: There is a workaround here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/199676/173554

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, I think this question has already been asked and answered...

[Keyboard shorcut to switch focus between multiple displays on OS X Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106559/keyboard-shorcut-to-switch-focus-between-multiple-displays-on-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: The solutions provided in that link are not working anymore