# Keyboard shortcut to switch focus between monitors (from #1 to #2) in Yosemite

Tags: macos, keyboard, display, window-manager

I like having my IDE on left screen and browser on the right one. Whenever I want to refresh page in the browser, I need to move hand from keyboard to mouse. In my previous setup on Fedora I was able to setup a keyboard shortcuts <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to focus on the topmost window of appropriate monitor. I feel like this is a very basic task, but I didn't find any solutions. I even read this question:

[Keyboard shorcut to switch focus between multiple displays on OS X 10.9.5 + (mavericks, el capitan, sierra)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106559/keyboard-shorcut-to-switch-focus-between-multiple-displays-on-os-x-mavericks)

but it proposes a workaround instead of an actual keyboard shortcut to switch focus. Is there any solution? I am able to buy an app from AppStore if there is one for this purpose, but I would like to avoid non-AppStore apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch **Applications** by using <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. Tabbing through the list of applications can be done by holding the <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> key and continually hitting <kbd>tab</kbd>. This will automatically shift focus to the selected app no matter which screen or monitor on which it resides.

Therefore, swapping between IDE and browser is easily done without mapping new shortcuts.

The keyboard command for refreshing the browser is generally <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

You can switch **Windows of the same app** by using <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>.

Comment: I missed the fact that command+tab stack is reordered everytime I use it; okay this is a fair substitute

Comment: Yes, that works in many cases, but sometimes you may not have any apps on a screen, or switch to an app in another desktop on the other screen (so you'd have to switch to the current app on that screen then e.g. ctrl-right-arrow). Is there another way??

Comment: I have two windows of the same app, open on separate screens. I only get one instance of that app with cmd-tab, so I can't switch to the other screen, only the most recently focused instance. I want to switch to the other screen, to whichever window is visible there.

Comment: Use Command + ~ to switch between windows of the same app when app is in focus.