# Change space of other non-active display via keyboard

Tags: keyboard, spaces

My two displays (let call them `A` and `B`) have separate spaces. I can go back and forth among the spaces on the active/focussed display `A`. Is it possible to go back and forth among the spaces on `B` with keyboard shortcuts and without moving the focus to `B`?

I do not mean assigning keyboard shortcuts to each space, because there are more than ten spaces and plenty of maximized windows.

Answer (score 4):

There is another question here on Ask Different that answer this question:  [Keyboard shorcut to switch focus between multiple displays on OS X 10.9.5 + (mavericks, el capitan, sierra)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/106559/119271)

Here's the quick summary:

There are some utilities (window managers) that allow you to assign a keyboard shortcut to the focus of a specific monitor.  They are as follows (links provided):

- Catchmouse (No longer available so it's a moot point here)
- [Divvy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/divvy-window-manager/id413857545?mt=12) - $13
- [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) - $13
- [Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate) - Open Source, Free.  Functional, but there's a lot of manual configuration to be done here and not as easy as the paid software.

Comment: it is said that [this small script](https://github.com/jigish/slate/issues/458#issuecomment-209088893) solves the problem, I do no know where to put this script. [This answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116889/189271) reports that he solved my problem and gives [this config file for Slate](https://github.com/abbood/slateConfig/blob/master/.slate); but it did not work for me.

Comment: You put the scripts in your home directory.  I suggest you read the documentation:  [JavaScript Configs](https://github.com/jigish/slate/wiki/JavaScript-Configs).  If the script doesn't work, you should contact the author of the config/script.  Remember, this being open source **you** have to do a lot of the customization yourself.  If this is beyond your scope, you should look at one of the paid software applications.